# A query to substitute images paths in gutenberg (website migration)?

Tags: images, database, sql, block-editor, migration

I was used to do something like

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'http://dev.example.com/website', 'http://www.website.com');
```

This seems not to work anymore for texts that come from Gutenberg.

Any idea/update for this?

Comment: The Block Editor still keeps image URLs in the database, so if your query was working before, the editor isn't the reason it's not working now. Maybe your database has grown too large for the one query affecting every single post to run? You could try doing it in batches instead of every single post at once, i.e. include a `WHERE "ID" < 100` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the reason. It's because I'm using ACF Pro as Blocks. The data will be written in database in json format, and the urls will escape all the slashes ad double quotes. So for example

```
src=\"http:\/\/dev.example.com\/website\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/10\/identity.jpg\"
```

So I should add a row like this:

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'http:\/\/dev.example.com\/website', 'http:\/\/www.website.com');
```